# laravel get sender http host with JWTAuth

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-jwt

I'm using [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) to create an api. And I need to **get the URL of API request sender**. So I wrote a middleware and used,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd(request()->getHttpHost());      
    }
```

This gets the only api URL. And then I tried,

```
$request->header('referer');
```

I get an only a null value. Is there any way to achive this task?

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar question and found a solution.
If I call my Laravel 8 API and look for the headers, these may come useful:

```
host: ["127.0.0.1:8000"]
origin: ["http://localhost:3000"]
referer: ["http://localhost:3000/"]
```

So then I know that [`host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) is where API is hosted, [`origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) and [`referer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer), they have some difference tho.
Your problem may be caused because you try to access them from middleware, try to check them directly from a controller.
Also if you need sender hostname in a clear look, you can use this code:

```
public function SomeController(Request $request)
    {
        $host = explode('/', $request->header('origin'))[2]
        // Or with the referer
        $host = explode('/', $request->header('referer'))[2]
```

If you still get `null` in the response, you can simply debug it, just check for all headers:

```
$headers = $request->header()
```

Comment: Thnks bro will chk